# Matched two-terms asymptotic expansion for $\varepsilon^2 y'''' - y'' + 1 =0$

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I am trying to solve a textbook problem frim Hinch: Perturbation methods:
$$
  \varepsilon^2 y'''' - y'' + 1 =0\\
  y = y' = 0 \mbox{ for } x =  0 \mbox{ and }1.
$$
]
I need to find two terms in $\varepsilon$ in outer region and match it to inner solution near both boundaries.

I tried to find solution in outer region in the form of
$$
  y_{outer} = y_0 + \varepsilon y_1 + \mathcal O(\varepsilon^2),
$$
which yielded:
$$
  y_{outer} = \left[\frac{x^2}{2} + a_1 x + a_2 \right] + \varepsilon \left[a_3x + x_4 \right].
$$

Next I found inner solution in re-scalled variabe $X=x/\varepsilon$ near $x=0$, which was:
\begin{align}
 Y(X) =& B_1 \left(e^X - X - 1 \right) + B_2\left(e^{-X} + X -1 \right)\\
       &+ \varepsilon \left[ C_1 \left(e^X - X - 1 \right) + C_2\left(e^{-X} + X -1 \right)\right]
\end{align}

However, I am unable to match these two expansions. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand your $y_{outer}$, shouldn't the epsilon part be $\varepsilon[a_3e^{x/\sqrt{\epsilon}}+a_4e^{-x/\sqrt{\epsilon}}]$ ? Also the rescale should be $X=x/\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ instead, and this should affect the $x^2/2$ term as there is no arbitrary coefficient to absorb it.

Comment: You are right, I have forgotten the second power in the fourth-derivative $\varepsilon^2 y''''$. Now it is fixed.